# Matlab - Remove zero rows in cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, zero, cell-array

I have a 1x6 cell array. In cells 1-4 and 6 I have a 5000x1 cell array that contains strings. In the fifth cell I have a 5000x1 cell array that contains numbers. Well, I want to remove the rows for which I have 0s in the fifth cell. To make sure, it is clear:

string string string string 35 string

string string string string  0 string

string string string string 42 string

string string string string 10 string

string string string string  0 string

I have found a similar question in the forum for a 1x2 cell, but I cannot figure out how to do it in this specific case.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your example can you make it clearer? What exactly is string ... 35 string ...? Is it the 5th cell from which you want to remove the 0's?

Comment: Sorry, in the preview seemed that everything was properly sorted. I want to remove the rows that have a 0 in the fifth cell. The strings are codes that are needed for a correct interpretation of the data. Thus, if I have a 0 element, I do not need the codes either. Is this clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your cell array is stored in the variable `c`.  First, we can determine which of the rows of element 5 are not equal to `0` using a logical operation:

```
notZeros = (c{5} ~= 0);
```

Then, loop through the elements and apply the [logical index](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) to filter out the zero rows:

```
for k = 1:6
  c{k} = c{k}(notZeros);
end
```

---

You can also use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html).  It maybe slower but may also be more readable:

```
c = cellfun(@(c_el) c_el(notZeros),c,'UniformOutput',false);
```

"`'UniformOutput',false`" is a required option since the filter outputs vectors which, [as understood by the function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html#inputarg_UniformOutput), is a nonuniform result.